# using arrayList elements in more than one activity

Tags: android

i have a problem with got a from arraylist at same selected possition from listView and pass both values to nxt activities my code pass only the value of selected item from the list view but when put the ListAdaptername.get(position); it dosent back the value of the element  here's my code:

//part of sending the value to nxt activiti

```
 lv = getListView();
                   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

                    setListAdapter(adapter); 

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id)
                        {//getApplicationContext

                            //String bb=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            String name=names.get(position);
                               Intent i = new Intent(LastActivity.this, Details.class);
                               String des=desc.get(position).toString();

                                i.putExtra("Name",name);
                                i.putExtra("desc",des);
                                // starting new activity
                              startActivity(i);
                                //LastActivity.this 
                        }
                    });
```

}

//here's wher i define the lists and call the values:

```
ListView lv;

    static String UName="OName";
    static String UniUrl="Odesc";
    public String val;
    static List<String> desc;
    static ArrayList<String> names;

    URL url;
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    XmlPullParser xpp;
    boolean insideItem;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        links=new ArrayList<String>();
        names=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

          url=new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
            insideItem = false;


                    // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            int x=0;
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                            insideItem = true;

                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(OName)) {

                            if (insideItem)

                                names.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline

                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Odesc)) {

                            if (insideItem)

                                desc.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article

                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){

                        insideItem=false;

                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element

                }


        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Seems you are a little confused - where exactly do you extract the values from the the intent in OnCreate, this seems to be what your question is about but the code for Activity Detail never seems to touch the initiating intent

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.details);
  
  tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
  url=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
  Intent intent=getIntent();
  
         // receiving  data
         String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
         String path=intent.getStringExtra("desc");
         
         //Log.e("Second Screen", name + ".");
         tv.setText(name);
         url.setText(path);
 }

Comment: this is the details activity @Elemental the above comment

Answer (score 0):

You don't see to ever get the intent on your second block of code, try using something like this:

```
String names = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
```

If that does not work, maybe try hard coding your inital i.putExtra to double check that the data is being sent through is not empty.

```
i.putExtra("Name","Test Name");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: will seems like it sent empty:( i tried a test name but dosent show in the list view at the second activity.Thanx anyway:)))